# Cortex-M4: LDRD or VLDR.64 to move uint64_t

Tags: c++, assembly, cortex-m

The following code produces

```
volatile uint64_t x1;
volatile uint64_t x3;

int main(){
    while(true) {
        x3 = x1;
    }
}
```

uses `LDRD`/`STRD` to transfer the double word. In outher situations, where more registers are used, the compiler generates e.g. `vldr.64 d7, [r5]`  and `vstr.64 d7, [r4]`.

The compiler used is gcc 13.2 on Arch-Linux with `-mthumb -mcpu=cortex-m4 -mfpu=fpv4-sp-d16 -mfloat-abi=hard -O3`.

As I understand `vldr.64` are floating-point instructions. So, what are the implications of using these instructions?

Comment: One loads into a pair of general purpose registers, one into a VFP register.  Both achieve the same goal, but the datum ends up in a different place.  No other implication.

Comment: @fuz: Not even for store-forwarding between FP stores and integer loads or vice versa?  I guess not on Cortex-M4 which probably doesn't have a store buffer.  And maybe not on high-performance CPUs if `ldrd` / `strd` run as a single 64-bit access to cache / store-buffer.  Or at two 32-bit accesses if that's how the VFP instructions also do it on some CPUs.

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree there can and likely will be microarchitectural differences.  I was answering the question from the perspective of what the effect of these instructions is.